# Rewrite code with fewer characters

Tags: code-golf

How could I rewrite the following code such that the output (evaluation result) is the same, but is obtained from code having less than 30 characters in total?

```
Table[Table[{b - a, b}, {b,8}],{a,8}],
```

I tried for more than an hour, but I can't find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Table[{b - a, b}, {a, 8}, {b, 8}] is 26 characters.

Answer (score 11):

is 22 chars ok?

```
{#2-#,#2}&~Array~{8,8}
```

Comment: Thank you to both of you, it worked! :D

Comment: code-golf is fun!